# How to display all my files by date modified?

Tags: php, directory

I'm new to PHP and i was just wondering if someone could help. I want my code to read files from a directory/sub directory and display all of them by the date they were modified! My code displays only one file, which is the one that I recently changed. So how do I list all the files? I hope this question makes some sense..

```
<?php

   $last_mtimes = array(); 
   function ListFiles($dir) {

      if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

         $files = Array();
         $inner_files = Array();

         while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
               if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                  $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                  if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
               } else {
                  array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                  $lmtime = filemtime($dir . "/" . $file) ;
                  $last_mtimes[$lmtime] = $dir . "/" . $file;
               }
            }
         }

        krsort($last_mtimes);

        closedir($dh);
        return ($last_mtimes);

     }
   }

   foreach (ListFiles('folder/folder/') as $key=>$file);

   echo array_shift(ListFiles('folder/folder/'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra semi colon which makes the loop do nothing:

```
 foreach (ListFiles('folder/folder/') as $key=>$file);
                                                     ^ remove this
```